# Adobe Font Folio fonts unreadable on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, fonts

Some of the fonts can't be read. The fonts are from Adobe Font Folio. I've noticed that the ones which can't be read are ones which are missing a .inf file. What is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts):

> .inf (INFormation) files contain application-specific information in plain ASCII text, such as font menu names for Windows and DOS-based applications. When a font is installed in Windows, the ATM Installer software takes the AFM and the INF file as input and generates the required PFM file at installation time. The AFM and INF files are not installed in the user's system.

So you only really need the inf file when working with PFM fonts or when certain applications require it.

A majority of the fonts are Open Type Fonts (.otf) which are compatible with windows 7. The test are True Type Fonts (.ttf) which are also compatible with windows. If you are missing a font that should be installed, you can find the font file and double click on it to preview the font and then install it.

[List of included fonts](http://www.adobe.com/products/fontfolio/pdfs/fontfolio11_font_list.pdf)

If you bought this recently, you can contact Adobe support to help get the fonts installed. You may have to re-download the files.